# How to set the default diff tool for `git difftool`

Tags: git

I have a customized diff tool which works as `git difftool -x mydiff.exe`, but it does't work even if I tried to set GIT_EXTERNAL_TOOL and `git config diff.external`, how could i make a default tool path/name for `git difftool`?

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this in my `.gitconfig`:

```
[difftool "bbdiff"]
        cmd = bbdiff --wait --resume --ignore-spaces "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

This sets the tool "bbdiff" as my editor for `git difftool`.

Comment: This seems doesn't work for my diff tool. I am using windows and `git difftool` still trying to find Visual Studio (devenv.exe) as difftool.